# Example for two sequences bounded

Tags: real-analysis

I am struggling with finding $2$ examples of sequences $a_n,n\geq1$ $b_n,n\geq 1$ that are bounded such that
 $a_n<b_n$ for all $n$, but $\sup(a_n)\geq \sup(b_n)$.

I have been thinking for more than three days, this question I got it from Analysis I, written by Terence Tao. I will appreciate any help

Comment: Such that ....what  ?

Comment: such that
 a_n<b_n for all n, but sup(a_n)not< sup(b_n).

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to write  it

Comment: Hint: you can take $b_n$ constant. What does this mean for $a_n$?

Comment: Got it Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take *any* bounded increasing sequence $b_n$ with limit $L$ and let $a_n=3b_n-2L.$

Comment: You might prefer Siong Thye Goh's answer, which is much more general.

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

Pick your sequence of $b_n$.

Let $a_n = b_n - c_n$ where $c_n$ is a positive sequence that converges to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can take $a_n=-\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n=0$

And $a_n=\frac{n}{n+1}$ and $b_n=1$